# Can't understand strategy exit and Pyramiding

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

Following is my code

```
strategy("50 pips a day", shorttitle = '50 pips' , overlay = true , pyramiding = 1)

tradestart = time == timestamp("GMT+0" , year , month , dayofmonth , 7 , 0 , 0)

bgcolor( tradestart ? color.silver : na, transp = 0)

if tradestart
    strategy.entry('Buy' , long = true , stop = high , oca_name = 'Breakout' , oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel )
    strategy.entry('Sell' , long = false  , stop = low , oca_name = 'Breakout' , oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel)
    strategy.exit('Buy Exit' , from_entry = 'Buy' , profit = 50 * 10)
```

[image: Strategy Exit]
My condition states that after 15:00 (which has the transparent background  color) , there should be a Buy Order

a. Why is there a Buy Exit at 15:00[I am in GMT +8 ZONE] when my condition clearly states to go Long after 15:00?

b. What does Pyramiding exactly mean ?  Does it mean if I set pyramiding to 1 , then I can place only one Buy Order until I exit it ? And if I set pyramiding to 2 , then I can only place 2 Buy Orders Until I exit both of it ? I genuinely can't understand this concept.

c. strategy.exit('Buy Exit' , from_entry = 'Buy' , profit = 50 * 10),means we take profit from 50 pips right? Is this 50 pips from the close price of the candle?

d. How do I see the profit price as highlighted in purple color in my image? Is there a way to see it on the data window?

Thank you to anyone who can answer my questions

Answer (score 2):

> a. Why is there a Buy Exit at 15:00[I am in GMT +8 ZONE] when my condition clearly states to go Long after 15:00?

I suppose this exit was from previous entry.

> b. What does Pyramiding exactly mean ? Does it mean if I set pyramiding to 1 , then I can place only one Buy Order until I exit it ? And if I set pyramiding to 2 , then I can only place 2 Buy Orders Until I exit both of it ? I genuinely can't understand this concept.

Yes. If the pyramiding == 1 then you can open only one entry in same direction (long or short). If the pyramiding == 2 then you can open only one or two entry in same direction. Etc.

> c. strategy.exit('Buy Exit' , from_entry = 'Buy' , profit = 50 * 10),means we take profit from 50 pips right? Is this 50 pips from the close price of the candle?

`profit = 50 * 10` means that you set up 500 points profit offset from position entry price.

> d. How do I see the profit price as highlighted in purple color in my image? Is there a way to see it on the data window?

No, there are no any order information in the Data Window. You can see execution price of orders in the Trade List in the bottom panel under the chart.